# SQL Query in VB.NET keeps giving me an error with wildcards

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm trying to execute this SQL query on my database with VB.NET:

```
Dim sql As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `personer` WHERE epost LIKE %" _
            & txbEpost.Text, tilkobling)
```

The problem is that it keeps getting an error, and I have no idea why. It keeps saying that there's a syntax error near 'gmail.com' (given I've written gmail.com in txbEpost.Text). But running the exact same query in my web interface MySQL yields the expected results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should use MySqlParameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first problem in your code is the missing quote around a string value

```
"... WHERE epost LIKE '%" & txbEpost.Text &"'"
```

However, this query should be done using parameters to avoid sql injection and other parsing problems (what if the textbox contains a single quote?)

```
Dim sql As New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `personer` WHERE epost LIKE @epost"
sql.Parameters.Add("@epost", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & txbEpost.Text
```

Comment: Hm, I tried that, but now when I try to fill my DataTable it says that the input data is formatted incorrectly.

This is the code: http://pastebin.com/kaf78AWH
It throws an error when txbEpost.Text equals "gmail.com"

Comment: @Steve would it be worth placing `%` here `LIKE + '%' + @epost`?

Comment: When I replaced the `MySqlDbType.VarChar` with `"%" & txbEpost.Text`, and removed `.Value` it worked wonders! Thanks!

Comment: @gloriousCatnip Uhm, It is not clear what you have changed. In the code above the Add method returns a parameter whose value should be set to the string you want to use in the LIKE expression (minus the quotes). Can you post your actual line?

Comment: @Bugs Yes, I think it is possible to use also that syntax, but when possible I try to avoid any concatenation in the command text. Perhaps it is just an habit.

Comment: @Steve I have changed it because it didn't work, but now this line works: `sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epost", "%" & txbEpost.Text)`


I used this before in the example above:
`sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@epost", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" & txbEpost.Text`

Comment: The second parameter of AddWithValue is the value for the parameter, in my example above I use Add to be more precise on the DataType of the parameter. See [Can we stop using AddWithValue already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) but in case of strings there is no big difference (a part performances with optimizing engines that keep track of the string passed)

Answer (score -1):

hi there  think that should work

```
MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROMpersonerWHERE epost LIKE '%" _
            & txbEpost.Text & "'", tilkobling)
```

because of your sql string is missing the  "'". The quote is necessary

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. When it comes to answering these types of questions _always_ suggest parameters and get into the habit of doing it yourself. Steve's answer shows how it should be done.

Answer (score -1):

how about this:

> MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROMpersonerWHERE epost LIKE '%" &
>   txbEpost.Text & "%'", tilkobling)

Comment: This is open to SQL injection. When it comes to answering these types of questions _always_ suggest parameters and get into the habit of doing it yourself. Steve's answer shows how it should be done

Comment: Thanks @Bugs for the heads up,, then show your answer here if you have.

Comment: Not a problem. As for answering, normally I would however I don't need to in this case as Steve has done a nice job of it already. It's how I would do it too. It would be pointless providing a duplicate answer.

Comment: how about if use like this after like condition str.Format("{0}{1}{2}", "'%", txbEpost.Text, "%'")

Comment: It's the concatenating strings that can cause SQL injection. Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). It may prove useful.